# Как узнать, какой масштаб (зум) нужно взять, чтобы маркеры были видны на карте?

Tags: android, java, google-maps-api-2

День добрый

Есть карта, на ней 2 маркера, карта отцентрирована посредине, между точками.

Как узнать, какой масштаб(зум) нужно взять, чтобы оба маркера были видны на карте???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так

```
LatLngBounds.Builder baseBuilder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
for (final LatLng latLng : latLngList)
    baseBuilder.include(latLng);

if (latLngList.size() > 0)
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(baseBuilder.build(), 30));
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробуем)